# SQL Server - Add seconds to time field

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

I need to add 8 seconds to a time (e.g. `15:49:12.8080000`), but its stored as `varchar`.

How do I go about it? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: OK , so how do you convert back to time>

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: Also storing datetime values in varchar fields is never a good idea, use DATETIME datatype for your column.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way of doing that if you have 2008+ -

```
update yourtable set timecolumn = dateadd(s, 8, cast(timecolumn as time))
from tbl
```

see sqlfiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/efdad/2

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it for few rows, than you can do by just manually updating, column is `varchar`:

assuming original value was : `15:49:12.8080000`

```
update table set time_column = "15:49:20.8080000" .....
```